# PostgreSQL 9.0 and PHP on Amazon EC2

Tags: php, centos, amazon-ec2, postgresql, pdo

How can I enable PostgreSQL 9.0 support in PHP on my Amazon EC2 instance? I'm running the free 32 bit Linux Micro instance. I've installed PostgreSQL 9.0 by following these instructions http://www.imperialwicket.com/aws-install-postgresql-90-on-amazon-linux

If I install the php-pgsql package using yum, it only supports PostgreSQL 8.4.7. Ultimately I'd like to use PostgreSQL 9.0 through PDO.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running an Amazon Linux AMI (as per the referenced instructions), then it is basically CentOS binary-compatible.  You can follow the steps that would normally be taken for CentOS or ask for help on CentOS forums.  I've added the CentOS tag in case experts here might be able to help out.